# Find out total number of pages in global query on archive page?

Tags: wp-query, pagination

I'm trying to find out whether there is more than one page of posts (I've set my posts per blog page to 5 in the reading settings) in a custom category template.

I would think the global query would have the total number of pages as a property but I can't find the call to it.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
global $wp_query;
echo $wp_query->max_num_pages;
```

This shows the number of pages for the current query. If you want to determine the actual number of posts found by the current query, you may use `$wp_query->found_posts`

Source:- http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Answer (score 0):

To this day, Mridul Aggarwal answer is not only valid, but vital to use **the_posts_pagination()** function in some loops scenarios

```
global $wp_query;
the_posts_pagination();
```